# Read Blob file without saving it a file

Tags: java, jdbc, blob, resultset

I have planned to encrypt a string using a public key which is stored in a database as Blob.I have created method called `readBlob()` to read the key and save it to the file.

```
  public static void readBlob(int userid, String filename) throws SQLException, IOException {
      String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bank";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "root";
        String email=null;

            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            String sql = "select * from users where user_id=?";
            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setLong(1, userid);
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
            File file = new File(filename);
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
            String keys=null;

    while(result.next()) {
         byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
         InputStream input = result.getBinaryStream("key");
         while (input.read(buffer) > 0) {
             output.write(buffer);
            }        
        }
  }
```

It worked really well but I don't need to save it to the local file ,I need a way to read the Blob without saving it.

Comment: It doesn't work at all. You aren't writing the amount read each time, so you are writing junk to the file. There is nothing that says you have to write it anywhere. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [getBlob](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBlob(java.lang.String))

```
Blob key = result.getBlob("key")
```

> Retrieves the value of the designated column in the current row of this ResultSet object as a Blob object in the Java programming language.

Comment: After reading the key i have to pass the key to another method which is readPublicKey(InputStream in). So how do i convert it to inputStream?

Comment: @Rahul `getBinaryStream()`