# Download blob object as a string instead of saving it as a file and then read it

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, blobstore

Say I have a storage at Google containing a `blob_file`

```
{"name":"my name",
"number:"my number"
}
```

is there a way to download this file and return the download as a plain string instead of saving it as a file e.g

```py
import json
from google.cloud import storage

downloaded_json = storage.blob.some_function(bucket_name="mybucket",blob_file="blob_file") #Gets the context of "blob_file" as a string

print(downloaded_json)
#'{"name":"my name",
#"number:"my number"
#}'
name_dict = json.loads("downloaded_json") #Convert it to a dictionary such that it can be used

print(name_dict["name"])
#"my name"
```

I am aware that I can download the file, read the file, delete the file - but it is to avoid this and it seems like, you can do so in [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58678762/read-blob-file-without-saving-it-a-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `download_as_text` function that is documented in the Google Cloud Storage client library [here](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html)